# Make handwritten text darker - Pdf file

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, foxit-reader, contrast, handwriting

I scanned handwritten notes, but the text is too gray and when I print it, it is difficult to read. I tried to adjust "contrast" by using many software (adobe acrobat, foxit, nitro pdf), but without success. Can you suggest me a way to reach the goal please?

P.S.: online I found ScanWritr which does what I want, but adds adv in the sheet.

[image]

EDIT no camera raw in filter menu in Photoshop

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in Photoshop's CameraRaw, but any image editor with similar curves adjustment could do similar. [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org) is a freeware editor, similar to Photopshop.

Push the lights, pull the darks, roughly speaking…

[image]

and you end up with…

[image]

In future, you could save all the trouble with a black ink or softer pencil ;)

After edit, this is what I see in Photoshop. Maybe you got Photoshop Elements, which probably doesn't have so many options.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Tetsujin thank you a lot for the suggestions! It seems that  Camera raw is free https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5294-adobe-camera-raw.html

Comment: I don't know if it works inside Acrobat - never tried it. It comes as part of photoshop so I've never tried using it in any other situation.

Comment: yes it can be used if you have photoshop. How many pdf pages can I import in photoshop? Maybe every pdf file is ok?

Comment: I've never tried. I very rarely work in pdf. I tested a 485 page technical manual with no issues, but it might be different if your entire document is pictures rather than text (also may depend on scratch disk size & RAM)

Comment: I installed the trial version of Photoshop and then the plugin camera raw. If I click on file->open in camera raw, Photoshop said "This file cannot be opened as it's an unsupported file type." How did you open it?

Comment: Open in photoshop, then switch to camera raw from within. Cmd/Opt/A (which I guess would be Ctrl/Alt/A on windows)

Comment: I tried with Ctrl+Alt+A, but nothing happens..is there a path to follow maybe?

Comment: Filter menu>camera raw - I did just realise it's Shift, not Alt (I do it so much it's just a 'pattern' rather than the keys, sorry)

Comment: please see the edit of my question. I tried also Ctrl+Alt+A, but it doesn't work

Comment: I really don't know. I've never used Photoshop on Windows. It's something you need to ask Adobe about. This what I see - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzwaZ.png Are you sure you got the full Photoshop, or the cut-down 'Elements' which probably doesn't have everything.